Operator norm between isomorphic spaces with equivalent norms
Let us consider two Banach spaces $X,Y$ which are isomorphic with equivalent norms, i.e. there exists $C_1,C_2>0$ such that,
$$C_1\| x \|_Y \leq \|x\|_X \leq C_2\| x \|_Y.$$
Now suppose we have a bounded linear operator $T:X \rightarrow X$. Moreover we can think on the same operator defined on the space $Y$ as $T:Y\rightarrow Y$.
Question:
Which is the relation between the norms $\|T\|_{X \to X}$ and $\|T\|_{Y \to Y}$.
My attempt:
And easy computation gives that,
$$
\|Tx\|_{Y} \leq C_1^{-1} \|Tx\|_{X} \leq C_1^{-1} C_2 \, \|T\|_{X \to X} \,\|x\|_{Y}, 
$$
and
$$
\|Tx\|_{X} \leq C_2 \|Tx\|_{Y} \leq C_1^{-1} C_2 \, \|T\|_{Y \to Y} \,\|x\|_{Y}.
$$
Letting $K = C_1^{-1} C_2 $, we obtain
$$
 K^{-1} \|T\|_{Y \to Y} \leq \|T\|_{X \to X} \leq K \|T\|_{Y \to Y}.
$$
Is there a better relationship?

No, this is the best you can do.

You won't really be able to tell much more since this would already be optimal for $T = \operatorname{Id}$ if the infimum of viable $C_2$s is still $> 1$ (for example if you set $\|x\|_Y = C \|x\|_X$ with $C < 1$).
